# Yodlee getSiteLoginForm handling and testing all the field types

Tags: yodlee

I am implementing the [Yodlee Update Site Account flow](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Update_Site_Account).

I am having some issues understanding how to display some field types that can be sent in json from a [getSiteLoginForm](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getSiteLoginForm) call :

What supposed to be displayed to the user for the types of field below ?

- URL : is the user supposed to enter an url or are we supposed to display an url ?
- HIDDEN : is it an input de type hidden ?
- IMAGE_URL : do we have to display a captcha and expect the user to enter its value ?
- CONTENT_URL : What do we have to display ?
- CUSTOM : What do we have to display ?
- CLUDGE : What do we have to display ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating site account credentials you have to use [updateSiteAccountCredentials](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/updateSiteAccountCredentials) API. Treat this as simple add account process where you have had used [addSiteAccount1](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/addSiteAccount1) API, its just instead of passing siteId you have to pass memSiteAccId, rest of the fields remains same.

Coming to the details you are asking- generally you should show only fields which requires user inputs like username, password or any other such fields. If bank ask for anything additional parameters then you have to ask those as well. You don't have to ask for URL, Content URL etc fields.

I am attaching an image of Fastlink 2.0, how it renders such fields.[image]

Recommendation- You should use Fastlink 2.0, as this will help you to integrate quickly and you do not have to worry about what should be displayed to the user.

Read more about Fastlink 2.0 [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Fastlink_2.0).

Comment: So, URL, HIDDEN,IMAGE_URL,CONTENT_URL, CUSTOM and CLUDGE should not be displayed in form ?

Comment: No, it should not. Unless you have any specific need for it. If you have to display  you can show login URL or Base URL.